# Rank of matrix containing NON parallel vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

> > Suppose $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are (row) vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and they are  **not** parallel, then what you can say about the rank of the matrix:
>
> \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \end{pmatrix}

The answer says $\text{rank } A > 1$, where $A$ is the matrix.

But why is this true?

**From the definition of rank**

> **Rank:** *The maximum number of linearly independent row vectors in the matrix. Both definitions are equivalent.*

Clearly, if $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are not parallel, then the set $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is a linearly independent set, so $\text{rank }A = 3$ should hold shouldn't it?

Comment: Do you consider $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(1,1,0)$ parallel?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, how? They arent scalar multiples of one another? I would consider ex $(1, 0, 0), (,2, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0)$ parallel

Comment: @Amad27 Exactly, they aren't parallel. They also aren't linearly independent.